# Accessing data trough relationship Laravel

Tags: laravel, relational-database

I have two tables/models. User and Advert.

When a user posts an advert their userid is a column in the database row. I want to use the id to get the user details and show it in a blade template.

These are the models

Advert belongs to a user.

```
class Advert extends Model
{    
    public function user(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

User has many adverts.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function advert(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Advert);
    }
}
```

On the advert show page I want the users name and details printed out beside it. Currently I can only access the ID as that is stored as a attirbute in the advert column in the DB. How can I use this relatonship to access the users data.

This is the show controller

```
public function show($id){
      //Shows add user clicked on based on id
      $user = User::where('id', $id)->first();
      $Advert = Advert::where('id', $id)->first();
      return view('pages/advert/show', compact('Advert', 'user'));

    }
```

In the show page view I can access the user id like so `{{$user->id}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `$id` passed into your `show` function for retrieving both the user and the advert.

```
public function show($id){
    // Get the avert with the passed in id
    $advert = Advert::find($id);
    // From the advert get the user related to it.
    $user = $advert->user;
    return view('pages/advert/show', compact('advert', 'user'));
}
```

Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations to get a better understanding of how eloquent works with relationships.